# html5 download and php download not working on mobile devices

Tags: php, html, download, http-headers, content-type

On my site I have a `<a download></a>` link and also a php function that downloads files on my desktop just fine -

```
ob_start();

$nameOld = 'https://my-other-server.online/path/to/file.mp4';
$save = '/var/path/to/file.mp4';
$nameNew = "download.mp4";

file_put_contents($save, fopen($nameOld, 'r'));

set_time_limit(0);

header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nameNew");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($save));

      while (ob_get_level()) {
        ob_end_clean();
      }

readfile($save);
exit;

unlink($save);
```

On mobile devices (iphone) this doesnt work on chrome browser. (Im already aware about safari ios downloads, even though I've seen some downloads prompt the user to open another app to continue.)

So I've tried using the `<a></a> download` link, but when clicking on it, it simply opens the video in a new tab and plays it.

If I try with a php script, it opens the video in a new tab and shows a crossed out play button (video is not even playable). I've been searching for an answer for days, I've edited .htaccess files and testing different scripts, content-types, headers, etc.

This is how the current script looks like for mobile specific -

```
... first few lines same as above script ...

file_put_contents($save, fopen($nameOld, 'r'));

//echo file_get_contents($save);
//$headers = get_headers($nameOld, 1);
//$filesize = $headers['Content-Length'];
//set_time_limit(0);

ob_clean();

//if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
               // ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
            //$fp = @fopen($save, 'rb');

//header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
//header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
//header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
//header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nameNew");    
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($save) . "\"");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
//header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($save));
//ob_end_clean();

     while (ob_get_level()) {
        ob_end_clean();
      }

//fpassthru($fp);
  //          fclose($fp);

readfile($save);
//exit;

unlink($save);    
die();
```

I also tried testing printing on mobile the headers of one of the files -

```
print_r(get_headers($url));
print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
```

The output today is as follows, but yesterday the content-type said `application/octet-stream` ---

```
Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [1] => Date: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 14:51:56 GMT [2] => Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) [3] => Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Feb 2019 14:16:19 GMT [4] => ETag: "3e7e3a-582ccb37e75a7" [5] => Accept-Ranges: bytes [6] => Content-Length: 4095546 [7] => Connection: close [8] => Content-Type: video/mp4 ) Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Date] => Wed, 27 Feb 2019 14:51:56 GMT [Server] => Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) [Last-Modified] => Tue, 26 Feb 2019 14:16:19 GMT [ETag] => "3e7e3a-582ccb37e75a7" [Accept-Ranges] => bytes [Content-Length] => 4095546 [Connection] => close [Content-Type] => video/mp4 )
```

I've also checked my php info settings and didnt see anything that could be causing an issue, but then again Im not too sure what to look for.

I know its possible to download files on chrome mobile because other sites work for me, just not my own.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're setting the MIME type to `video/mp4`. If the browser can play that kind of video, it will do so. Change it back to `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: It does not help to solve but you also have to think the user's browser need access to the filesystem of the device for this feature to work.

Comment: You can try to add this header  `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` +  the header with `application/octet-stream`

Comment: @miken32 i've already tried that.

Comment: @Tuckbros like this? - `header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');`

Comment: It is the idea. I let you look around, to see what it is for. No promise it will work. It is the most relevant header I saw when dowloading (on my computer, firefox on ubuntu) a file I could download on my phone (firefox on android).

Comment: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

Comment: maybe you need CORS

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same exact issue....

Answer (score 1):

Add this as a header : `'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff';`
it is made to prevent browsers from interpreting themself the received content.
In association wth `Content-disposition: attachment; ...` the browser should offer to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the format:

```
<a href="myvideo.mp4" download>Download</a>
```

And as miken32 mentioned :

"You're setting the **MIME type** to `video/mp4`. If the browser can play that kind of video, it will do so. Change it back to `application/octet-stream.`"

**EDIT:**
You could also try to set this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .mp4
```

And then change it back to `application/octet-stream.`

Try this.

Comment: i've already tried octet-stream. everything commented out is code combinations i've already tried. And yes the link is correct -- `<a id="dlLink" download href="/path/to/vid.mp4">proceed</a>`

Comment: @Rich if you go to the url and see the video, is there a download button?

Comment: what do you mean? if i go to the direct url of the video, it shows the video.

Comment: Does it show any controls underneath the video? I made an edit in my answer, maybe you can try that.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago trying to make a small application and the download tag just worked for me in Chrome. Like this:

`<a href="http://URL" download target="_blank"> Download </a>`